# Removing a hardcoded year value using a parameter on SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ta_punch_log pl
WHERE punch_date >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -((CAST([value] AS value)  FROM 
[dbo].[slxAppSetting] WHERE [key] = 'spotlightyearthreshold'))  ,GETDATE())), 0)
```

This is the query that is giving me the below error

> "  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'  ".

My company is using SSMS and this query change will be effective on a large number of datasets.  the original query is attached below

```
FROM dbo.ta_punch_log pl
WHERE punch_date >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE())), 0)
```

The logic (the need) to change this query is simply to remove the hardcoded "2" and replace it with a value from a look up table. the - (negative) sign was the reason for me to use CAST function as the value is coming from a table that was created as a varchar for the value we are looking for.

Are we able to make the query all the way on top? or is there an easier way to achieve the main goal .. which is replacing the number '2' from the query with a flagged value that comes from a parameter.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make it much easier to assist. But to access another table you either need a join or sub-query.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).